# What is the best place to make HTTP call when component receives props in the child component?

Tags: reactjs

What is the best place to make HTTP call when the component receives props in the child component?

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-keldysh-rivhz

I have `Test` child component. I have two option to call HTTP request when I receive new props

1. componentWillReceiveProps
2. componentDidUpdate

Where is the best place to make HTTP request? In my example I take `componentDidUpdate`, is that correct?

Comment: cWRP is [considered unsafe](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops).

Answer (score 0):

Use componentWillReceiveProps (deprecated) or it's replacement [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

> **getDerivedStateFromProps** is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

it avoids unnecessary re-render, as it is called before the render method.

you can use `componentDidUpdate` but it'll only after run updates, which means you'll have to invoke `getDerivedStateFromProps` for `componentDidUpdate` to see those changes.